# Browser opened by selenium webdriver does not let me do drag and drop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

The Web browser opened using selenium  webdriver is not letting me do a drag and Drop on my machine.I am using a windows 7 OS and Selenium webdriver 2.45.  It works fine when I do it on some other machine. Any one has any idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a windows issue because of Elevated rights. The IDE was opened with administrator rights and drag and drop was probhited. So its not a issue with Selenium.